# How to insert data into datatable from datagrid without using ItemSource in Wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, datagrid, datatable

I have a Datagrid which has DataView as ItemSource . Actually that DataGrid will not display all data which is in Dataview. i.e if dataview has 21 column but datagrid displayed only 13 column.Now i want to select those 13 columns and add it to New DataTable. I dont know how to do this. Please help me. Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`DataView.ToTable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h2b6ehaa(v=vs.110).aspx):

C#:

```
string[] columnNames = { " Col1", "Col2", "...", "Col13" };
DataTable newTable = view.ToTable("TableName", false, columnNames);
```

VB.NET:

```
Dim columnNames = { " Col1", "Col2", "...", "Col13" }
Dim newTable As DataTable = view.ToTable("TableName", False, columnNames)
```